# The new inserted value is replacing all values in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to store a value from a parameter to an array. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to push a value, it also changed the former value. So in the end, they all have same value but it shouldn't.

For example: I push "1". It store, but when I push "2", it replaced the "1"

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function Add(num) {
  var numArr = [];
  var count= 10;

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    numArr.push(num);
  }

  console.log(numArr);
}
```

Comment: What former value? `numArr` is created **inside** the `Add` function (anew, ever time the function is called) and is garbage collected when that function finished.

Comment: Is it normal behavior that the value is added 10 times?

Comment: The image log can't be the one of the code below, since the array must have 10 elements, neither 1, nor 2.

Answer (score 3):

Make the array global, when it is inside the function, whenever the function is called a new array is created. when array is global this problem does not arises

```js
var numArr = [];
function Add(num) {
  var count = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    numArr.push(num);
  }
  console.log(numArr);
}
Add(11)
Add(112)
```

Comment: If you have a more than one array to update, you can use array referance as a parameter also. For example; function Add(myArr, num) and Add(superArray, 11) and Add(superArray, 112)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the previous value is replaced is that with each function call you declare your array all over again, with no values in it `var numArr = []`. Move this definition outside this function and it should be just fine

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numArr = [];
const Add = (num) => {
  var count= num;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    numArr.push(num);
  }
  return numArr
}

console.log(Add(10))
```

Comment: you can use the arrow function, let as above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you instantiate the array in every iteration of the loop. The simple fix is to pass the array in to the `Add()` function.

```js
function Add(arr, num) {
  var count = 10;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    arr.push(num);
  }
}

var numArr = [];
Add(numArr, 999);
console.log(numArr);
```

You could alternatively declare the array outside of the function, but this ties the function logic to external variables which makes the point of the function entirely moot.

Also note that the function itself can be replaced with the [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Browser_compatibility) method which does exactly the same thing, but is unsupported in IE:

```js
var arr = new Array(10);
arr.fill(999);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you create new array when push new value.you can create global array and push value on it.

```js
<script>
_glb_arr=[];

$(document).ready(function (){
  Add(1);
  Add(3);
  console.log(_glb_arr);
});

function Add(val){
 _glb_arr.push(val);  
}

</script>
```